# Show the content of TabITem in the tooltip of TabITem header in WPF ( Google chrome new feature )

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, google-chrome

Google Chrome added recently a new feature in the latest update that allows the user to see the content of the other `tabItems` without selecting one.

This feature is important and can help users to show how the content is updated for each `tabItem`.

I would like to implement this feature in my WPF application, and I'm asking if there is similar functionality in C# that can do the job.

[image]

Is it possible to add something like this in my WPF application?

Comment: Surely you can. Probably create `WriteableBitmap` of TabItem content and show it in `Popup`.

Comment: The problem is not in the shown of the content , the problem is in the shown of the updated content ( real time content ) not a fixed content

Comment: `WriteableBitmap` is designed to be updated and so update it as you wish.

Comment: Did you have any idea how can I implement this ? I mean how can I make the content of tabItem in `WriteableBitmap` ?

Comment: @JuniorDev13 deleting a question while people are answeringis rude. Had you asked for the original problem, how to create and delete temporary files, people would point to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776031/how-to-create-a-temp-file-that-is-automatically-deleted-after-the-program-termin) and the answer that shows you can use `FileOption.DeleteOnClose`